# Discord OAuth2 - What's the difference between the OAuth2 URL links?

Tags: oauth-2.0, discord

I'm just trying to expand my discord bot capabilities, so I've decided to get started on making an OAuth2 application for my bot. Upon looking at the Developer Portal, I've noticed that there are [various OAuth2 URLs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2) that I can use for my application. So I was wondering what the differences are between links used. I know the three represent the base authorization, token, and token revocation, but what does that mean exactly? I don't have much experience in this field, so try explaining it to me like I'm five.

---

tl;dr: What do the three OAuth2 URLs each represent? What's the difference for each, specifically the meanings behind the "base authentication", "token", and "token revocation"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation explains it.

from the docs:

> The authorization code grant is what most developers will recognize as "standard OAuth2" and involves retrieving an access code and exchanging it for a user's access token. It allows the authorization server to act as an intermediary between the client and the resource owner, so the resource owner's credentials are never shared directly with the client.

The `https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize` link is for authorization of your application by a user/resource owner. which gives you a code. you use the code with the second link to `https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token` to get the token that you will to access content of the user/resource owner

Comment: That makes more sense now, thanks yet again!